# jinja2 how to remove microsecond in datetime

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

In a Jinja2 template I want to display the last login:

```
Last Login: {{ user.last_seen }}
```

`last_seen` is supposed to be a datetime object in sqlite.

It always gives me something like: `2014-07-27 23:09:36.467761`

How do I remove the microseconds part of that when displaying on my template?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are using the [*default* string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.__str__) of a `datetime` object, which is essentially the same as [calling `datetime.isoformat(' ')`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat), a format that includes the microseconds component.

If you want a different format, then do so explicitly, using the [`datetime.datetime.strftime()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime):

```
Last Login: {{ user.last_seen.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') }}
```

Alternatively, produce a new `datetime` object with the microseconds component set to 0, then interpolate that:

```
Last Login: {{ user.last_seen.replace(microsecond=0) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, a nice solution is `flask-moment`, where you can use the datetime object and specify how it is to be formatted, like so:

```
Last Login: {{ moment(user.last_seen).format('LLLL') }}
```

which would output like this:

```
Last Login: Tuesday, July 29 2014 11:55 AM
```

You could even use the `fromNow()` function

```
Last Login: {{ moment(user.last_seen).fromNow() }}
Last Login: 2 days ago
```

Comment: Don't forget to mention that this requires JS code on the client side to format the dates (code to load it included in the Flask-Moment package).